# Converting dataframe to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'times', the head of which looks like this:

```
year    month   day hour    minute  second
0   2015    02  03  01  12  04
1   2015    02  03  01  12  07
2   2015    02  03  01  12  11
3   2015    02  03  01  12  13
4   2015    02  03  01  12  17
```

When I try to put all of these together into a single datetime series like this:

```
timeData = pd.to_datetime(times)
```

it throws this error:

```
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

Why does it throw this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It works on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works for me as well.

But you can also try:

```
times.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(*x), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
times.T.apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(*x))
```